# select top 3rd record from a column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

how to select top 3rd record from a column in sql

Comment: reword/expand your question, otherwise it will get closed.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `Top`

```
select  top 3 columnname from table
```

More about [SQL TOP Clause](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_top.asp)

Comment: I've never seem the form clause before! Is that new for SQL Server 2005? :-)

Comment: Let he who has never tried to use the form clause cast the first negative comment!

Comment: it will not return 3rd record , it will return first 3 rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Top 1 col_name 
From (Select Top 3 col_name from tablename order by col_name desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  with tempTable(column1)
 as (
SELECT top(3) column1
FROM table1
ORDER BY column1DESC
) select top(1)column1 from tempTable
```

or

need to take first 3 records use

```
SELECT top(3) column1
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY column1DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

For top 3 records it's simple:

```
SELECT TOP 3 <column-name> FROM <table>
```

For the **third** record in a result set, try this page [How do I get the nth row in a SQL Server table?](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-get-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-server-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get the third row from the top.

```
;with cte as
(
select *, 
       row_number() over (order by number) as rn
from master.dbo.spt_values

)
select * 
from cte
where rn=3
```

To get the top third

```
select top (100.0/3) percent * 
from master.dbo.spt_values
order by number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
SELECT *
 FROM(
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [OrderBYColumn]) AS SrNo, 
             <Column1,Column2,Column3 ....> 
     FROM 
         TableName
     )    AS TableAlias
 WHERE 
     SrNo=3
```

Also for from and to range you can use

```
SELECT *
 FROM(
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [OrderBYColumn]) AS SrNo, 
             <Column1,Column2,Column3 ....> 
     FROM 
         TableName
     )    AS TableAlias
 WHERE 
SrNo between 3 and 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name limit 3
```